# Creating an EBook for Android Phone

Tags: java, android

I want to create an eBook that can be read in an android phone. Is there any eBook format for Android Phones. I have already created an ebook for desktop machine using Desktop Author Software.
Is there a way to display it on my Android phone.

Comment: This is not the best Q/A for your answer and google should know, if Desktop Author Software can produce ebooks that can be displayed on android or if some android apps exist that display DAS products

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android does not have any special format.
ePub is general e-book format which is accepted by many publishers.

Following link may use to convert desktop author to epub

http://www.dnaml.com/

Check following list of ePub Readers.

```
Aldiko  http://www.aldiko.com/
FBReader    http://www.fbreader.org/FBReaderJ/
pcr-book-reader http://code.google.com/p/pcr-book-reader/
Cool Reader http://sourceforge.net/projects/crengine/
Moon + Reader   http://www.moondownload.com/
```